# run IRB from Notepad++

Tags: ruby, notepad++, irb

From one of the stackoverflow post [`RubyPrompt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760115/ruby-prompt-when-stdin-isnt-a-terminal-for-notepad-explicitely):

I have seen that we can run `IRB` from Notepad++ also. The last answer from the above post I am talking about.

Can anyone out there help me about the configurations to run `IRB` from Notepad++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the `run` menu and choose `Run...`

Choose the button labeled `...` and locate the `irb.bat` file which is located at `path_to_ruby/bin/irb.bat`. Choose `open` and it will display the path to irb in the text field.

After the irb path in the text field, enter `-r "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`. The final text field should look something like:

```
C:\Ruby200\bin\irb.bat -r "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

Choose `Save...` and you can setup a Shortcut for this Run. I chose `F6` personally.

Now, write your Ruby file and hit `F6` or whatever you set as the shortcut. IRb will then launch with your current Ruby file loaded into the environment.

[Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/interactive_ruby.htm) and [Ruby Central](http://www.rubycentral.org/pickaxe/irb.html) have a list of some additional arguments you can pass to IRb that could also be used in the above example.

**EDIT:**

If you are more interested in running the IRb console from within Notepad++, You should check out the [NppExec](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/NppExec/) plugin. There is a good blog post on how to get it working for Python at [Raza Sayed's blog](http://razasayed.wordpress.com/2009/02/22/launch-your-program-from-within-notepad/). Just switch out Python for IRb.

A decent list of other Notepad++ plugins can be found on [their wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central)

Comment: Great! but how the IRB prompt will come? I am not getting any IRB prompt.

Comment: when I am hitting on F6 it opened a new window.

Comment: Here I am seeing one [console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760115/ruby-prompt-when-stdin-isnt-a-terminal-for-notepad-explicitely) to the last answer, which I am also looking for.

Comment: I would check to see if `F6` is mapped to something else. `Alt+F6` is mapped on my Notepad++ to open a new window.

Comment: Do you use  also Notepad++ to write Ruby script?

Comment: Opening an IRb prompt that is inside Notepad++ involves using the [NppExec](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/NppExec/) plugin.

Comment: I personally use RubyMine and Sublime Text 2. I use RubyMine for large projects and Sublime Text 2 for smaller ones. Notepad++ is a good tool as well.

Comment: Sorry, I am currently at work and the SO chat rooms are blocked.

Comment: I am downloading it via the `Notepad++` plugin manager,after download how to  launch that `IRB console`? guide me here

Comment: Excellent. Any idea how to do auto-syntax filling in `Notepad++` like `gedit` does. say If i do write `{` then `}` would come automatically?

Comment: I don't know of any setting off the top of my head. I would suggest digging into the plugins to find further functionality to add to Notepad++. I gave a link to a list of plugins in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. :) I am looking for a job, would you hire me?